# Можно ли найти 60 процентов от найденного значения calc(100% - 300px)?

Tags: html, css

Можно ли найти 60 процентов от значения - **calc(100% - 300px)**?

пробовал так, но пока безрезультатно:

```
width = 0.6 * calc(100% - 300px)
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Вопрос: Почему это не действует в таблицах с td? Синяя ячейка должна быть явно больше, чем зеленая.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style type="text/css">
    table{
      width: 100%;
    }
    td{
      padding-top: 30px;
    }
    .td_1{
      width: calc(calc(100% - 400px) * 0.9);
    }
    .td_2{
      width: calc(calc(100% - 400px) * 0.1);
    }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <table cellspacing = "0">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2", bgcolor="black"></td>
      <td colspan="2", bgcolor="red"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="200px", bgcolor="yellow"></td>
      <td class="td_1", bgcolor="blue"></td>
      <td class="td_2", bgcolor="green"></td>
      <td width="200px", bgcolor="orange"></td>
    </tr>
  </table> 
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ну, так всё выражение надо ещё в один `calc()` обернуть, не?

Comment: @UModeL делал так, тоже самое получается

Comment: похоже, что Вы делали как-то не так.

Comment: @UModeL я пробовал дать больше приоритетности td расположенным по центру, все равно не выходит

Comment: таблицы - это совершенно другой случай. И другой вопрос, соответственно.

Comment: @UModeL какую тему следует посмотреть, чтобы сделать это?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```css
div { box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px red; }
```

```html
<div style="width: 100%;">width = 100%</div>
<div style="width: calc(100% - 300px);">width = calc(100% - 300px)</div>
<div style="width: calc(calc(100% - 300px) * 0.6);">width = calc(calc(100% - 300px) * 0.6)</div>
```

Ну или так:

```css
div { box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px red; }
```

```html
<div style="width: 100%;">width = 100%</div>
<div style="width: calc(100% - 300px);">width = calc(100% - 300px)</div>
<div style="width: calc((100% - 300px) * 0.6);">width = calc((100% - 300px) * 0.6)</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Добавлю вариант, которому всех нас учили ещё в школе =)

```
20 конфет - 100%
....?.... -  60%

20 конфет умножаем на 60% и делим на 100%.
```

```css
div { box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px red; margin: 1px 0; }
```

```html
<div style="width: 100%;">width = 100%</div>
<div style="width: calc(100% - 300px);">width = calc(100% - 300px)</div>
<div style="width: calc(calc(100% - 300px) * 60 / 100);">width = calc(calc(100% - 300px) * 60 / 100)</div>
```

Comment: @UModeL а если это использовать в таблицах, например с td, я пробовал сдвиги не получаются(укажу проблему в вопросе)